# UPS VA vs battery current drain

Tags: power-supply, power, batteries, lithium-ion

My UPS is dead, or more correctly speaking, its battery is dead. I want to make a lithium battery pack to replace it instead of buying a new lead acid battery for it. Here are few questions:

1, it's rated at 350 VA / 200 W; Does that means that I need to provide 350va/12v=29.1 A from my lithium battery pack? It comes with a 3ah lead acid battery. Does it mean that this UPS was sucking almost 10c at that tiny sucker?

2, How large, in capacity, do I need my 12v 3-cells lithium battery to be? I got some tested 2ah 18650 from used laptop packs. If I use 9 of them, then it's a 6ah battery, and for 29A, It would be discharging @ 4.8C. Is it safe for typical laptop 18650 to discharge @ 4.8C?

Comment: You cannot just use li-ion batteries instead of lead acid one. You would have to change charging circuit as well.

Comment: @Chupacabras I know. I am not dumb. I have protection board for my lithium batteries. It should be fine.

Comment: Protection circuit on battery is NOT the charging circuit! Charging circuit is a part of UPS board.